# Упругие 2D столкновения

Tags: 2d, game-maker

Работаю на Game Maker 8 Pro, язык game maker language (GML). Мне нужно, чтобы объекты сталкивались передавая друг другу импульсы в зависимости от угла. Нужно упругое столкновение. На википедии я нашёл формулу, вот её первоисточник https://williamecraver.wixsite.com/elastic-equations. Также в интернете я нашёл пояснение к формуле http://new.math.uiuc.edu/math198/MA198-2013/dprorok2/FearTheSpherePPT.pdf. Сразу скажу, что в пояснении есть ошибка, а именно угол тета находится делением на скорости (vspeed/hspeed), а если hspeed=0 то крашится программа. Поэтому просто использовал direction, а фи искал как в пояснении.
Вот код:

```
if place_meeting(x+hspeed, y+vspeed, oWall) direction-=180  //чтобы шары не улетали за комнату
if inst[4]!=0 inst[4]-=1          //для кулдауна
inst[1]=collision_circle(x+hspeed,y+vspeed,12,oball,false,true)  `находим уникальный id того, кого тараним`
if inst[1]!=noone and inst[4]=0  //если id существует и кулдаун прошел, то сталкиваемся, используя формулу
{
    fi=arctan((y-inst[1].y)/(x-inst[1].x))
    teta1=degtorad(direction)  //директион от 0 до 360, зависит от hspeed и vspeed (если кто не знаком с GML)
    teta2=degtorad(inst[1].direction)  //с помощью id можно найти переменные определённого объекта
    v1x=inst[1].speed*cos(teta2-fi)*cos(fi)+speed*sin(teta1-fi)*cos(fi+pi/2)
    v1y=inst[1].speed*cos(teta2-fi)*sin(fi)+speed*sin(teta1-fi)*sin(fi+pi/2)
    v2x=speed*cos(teta1-fi)*cos(fi)+inst[1].speed*sin(teta2-fi)*cos(fi+pi/2)
    v2y=speed*cos(teta1-fi)*sin(fi)+inst[1].speed*sin(teta2-fi)*sin(fi+pi/2)
    hspeed=v1x
    vspeed=v1y
    inst[1].hspeed=v2x
    inst[1].vspeed=v2y
    inst[4]=3
    inst[1].inst[4]=3
    inst[13]=0
    inst[1]=0
}
if mouse_check_button(mb_right) instance_destroy()
```

Формулу я упростил, так как массы одинаковы. В одном месте ноль убирает часть формулы, а также деление забирает множитель 2 из формулы. В событии Create было создано массив inst 20 штук (используются только несколько). inst[4] это малый кулдаун, чтобы после столкновения шары успели убежать от очередного столкновения.
Формула работает неправильно, но не всегда. То работает, то шары аномально отскакивают. В чем моя ошибка? (при необходимости могу скинуть гмк)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P. S. (через дюжину дней) Я нашел скрипт для GM8Pro, который работает и шары отбиваются правильно, как в упругом столкновении. В принципе проблема решена, хотя почему я не смог приспособить формулу непонятно. Оставляю код для тех, кто, может быть, будет искать, как я информацию

```
if place_meeting(x+hspeed, y+vspeed, oWall) direction-=180  //чтобы шары не улетали за комнату
if inst[4]!=0 inst[4]-=1          //для кулдауна
inst[1]=collision_circle(x+hspeed,y+vspeed,12,oball,false,true)  //находим уникальный id того, кого тараним
if inst[1]!=noone and inst[4]=0 //это сам написал. выталкивает шарик из шарика (раньше работало, но я немного нахимичил поэтому надо расстояние правильно поставить)
{
    inst[2]=hspeed
    inst[3]=vspeed
    inst[5]=point_direction(x,y,inst[1].x,inst[1].y)
    inst[6]=point_distance(x,y,inst[1].x,inst[1].y)
    inst[7]=inst[6]-24 //это расстояние между объектами. У меня шары одинаковые и у них радиус по 12.
    if inst[7]>0
    {
        speed=inst[7]
        direction=inst[5]
        x+=hspeed
        y+=vspeed
    }
    if inst[7]<0
    {
        speed=abs(inst[7])
        direction=inst[5]
        x-=hspeed
        y-=vspeed
    }
    hspeed=inst[2]
    vspeed=inst[3]
    B1=id //а здесь начинается скрипт, что я нашел на одном форуме. Чучуть подрихтовал его. Там его вроде оптимизировать неплохо можно, но мне лень ;)
    B2=inst[1]
    dx = B1.x-B2.x;
    dy = B1.y-B2.y;
    coll_ang = arctan2(dy, dx);
    sp1 = sqrt(B1.hspeed*B1.hspeed+B1.vspeed*B1.vspeed);
    sp2 = sqrt(B2.hspeed*B2.hspeed+B2.vspeed*B2.vspeed);
    dir1 = arctan2(B1.vspeed, B1.hspeed);
    dir2 = arctan2(B2.vspeed, B2.hspeed);
    xspeed_1 = sp1*cos(dir1-coll_ang);
    yspeed_1 = sp1*sin(dir1-coll_ang);
    xspeed_2 = sp2*cos(dir2-coll_ang);
    yspeed_2 = sp2*sin(dir2-coll_ang);
    fxspeed_1 = ((B1.m-B2.m)*xspeed_1+(B2.m+B2.m)*xspeed_2)/(B1.m+B2.m);
    fxspeed_2 = ((B1.m+B1.m)*xspeed_1+(B2.m-B1.m)*xspeed_2)/(B1.m+B2.m);
    fyspeed_1 = yspeed_1;
    fyspeed_2 = yspeed_2;
    B1.hspeed = cos(coll_ang)*fxspeed_1+cos(coll_ang+pi/2)*fyspeed_1;
    B1.vspeed = sin(coll_ang)*fxspeed_1+sin(coll_ang+pi/2)*fyspeed_1;
    B2.hspeed = cos(coll_ang)*fxspeed_2+cos(coll_ang+pi/2)*fyspeed_2;
    B2.vspeed = sin(coll_ang)*fxspeed_2+sin(coll_ang+pi/2)*fyspeed_2;
    inst[4]=4
    B2.inst[4]=4
}
```

P.P.S. Кулдаун не нужен.